# Roof tip/extend edges

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm new to Blender so bare with me. I've used various 3D-modeling software before but struggling a bit to adapt to the Blender workflow.

I have a house were I accidently cut the roof tip of. I unfortunately can't undo it since I discovered it too late and had the number of undo steps set too low. So my question is, how can I model the tip back? Can I extend the edges somehow in their current trajectory to form new surfaces? Just to be clear, the house is mirrored, so I'm only modeling half of it.

Very grateful for any tips here!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can press GG to slide, then C to extend beyond the limit, but you'll have to cut a new vertical edge

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @moonboots ! Sliding the loopcut works well to join the roof but then I get a new angle. I'm not able to slide the vertices themself on the edge and of limit, but you're saying this should be possible?

Comment: Could you please share your object?

Comment: Oh, now I see it seems you have a _Mirror_ modifier on your object. In this case I have to slightly edit my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is for both cases: using a *Mirror* modifier or having a complete mesh.

1. Make sure you enable the *Auto Merge* function along with the option *Split Edges & Vertices* (although splitting is not necessary for the mirror version, but it does not matter). Also set the *Snap To* option to *Edge*.

   [image: auto merge]

**Using a *Mirror* modifier**

2. Select the top edge you want to slide (easiest to do in *Edge Select* mode), then press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to start edge sliding - make sure you move the cursor in a direction so it slides along the diagonal edges on the side (indicated in yellow), as soon as you got the correct direction press <kbd>C</kbd> to disable clamping, so you can slide beyond the top. Depending on if you have *Clipping* on or off in the *Mirror* modifier, sliding towards or beyond the center might look different - do not yet confirm the action:

   [image: sliding with and without clipping]
3. While sliding, hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to snap to the vertical center edge, then left-click to confirm.

   [image: snap to edge]

And that's it for the method with *Mirror* modifier. Now it depends on what you need/want to do with the front and back faces, merge them to n-gons or whatever.

**Full mesh without *Mirror* modifier:**

2. Select one of the top edges then press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to start edge sliding - make sure you move the cursor in a direction so it slides along the diagonal edges on the side (indicated in yellow), as soon as you got the correct direction press <kbd>C</kbd> to disable clamping, so you can slide beyond the top.

   [image: edge slide]
3. Slide the edge so far that it goes beyond the center where they should meet, then left-click to confirm the slide.
4. Now select the edge on the opposite side and slide without clamping by pressing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and then <kbd>C</kbd>, but this time hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to snap to the intersecting edge. This might not look great while you're doing it ;)

   [image: edge slide and snap]
5. After you have done the second slide, select the top edge and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*. That's important: **Dissolve Edges** and not (Delete) **Edges**. Otherwise one of the roof faces would be deleted, but of course you could easily create a new one.

   [image: dissolve edges]

   And it is finished, you now have the point top back.

   [image: finished rooftop]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Very useful and the version with a mirror modifier works well.